# Merging slope angle and aspect rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, merge, slope, aspect

I have created slope and aspect from a DEM layer, I reclassed both slope and aspect into categories (for example slope is now a value of 1-6) and turned them into polygon layers where each polygon has a different slope value etc. At the moment they are separate so I have polygons for aspect and polygons for slopes and I want to end up with one polygon layer where each polygon has a slope value and an aspect value, does anyone know how I might do this?

Comment: May I ask why?  Of course you can do this, but in most cases it is more efficient to keep your analyses as raster. If you edit your question to add a bit more context we might be able to suggest alternatives.

Comment: They are polygon layers so I can use them for zonal statistics to find out the density of vegetation present

Comment: If you are using them for zonal stats, you definitely don't want to convert to polygon as the polys will get converted back to raster in the zonal stats function.

Comment: Suggest you look at the "combine" tool. I'll add a proper answer tomorrow if no one else has.

Comment: Thankyou for all the help but I have managed to do it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [Union](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/union.htm) tool from Analysis tools->Overlay tool set. [Here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/how-union-analysis-works.htm) is a description on how it works.Although the link on how it works is for ArcGIS Pro, it also applies for ArcGIS Desktop.

Comment: Thankyou, this is exactly what I needed